# Community Building doesn't exist in Data Explorer

Tags: bug

"Community Building" doesn't exist in the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/). Instead it is still listed as "Moderators"

---

Other (seemingly) related issues:

- [Meta posts don't load from mobile apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244616/186281)
- [Meta post oneboxes look different and are missing elements](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/224/78)
- [Post/comments don't onebox in chat](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/223/78)

Comment: Actually, if someone bothers to fix this, Video Production is also still listed as Audio-Video Production in the Data Explorer.  Seems it is an oft-missed step of the name change.

Comment: [Known bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261517/sede-should-pick-up-on-changes-to-community-metadata), still not fixed, doubt it will be fixed as SEDE is low priority and there's no active developer working on it. /cc @AJHenderson.